# How to select middle element in listview in android onscroll?

Tags: android, listview

How can I select the middle element in a listview on scroll stop?
Suppose I have six elements and I am rotating it circularly. On stop of onscroll, I want to select the middle part on that listview. How can I do this?

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                     int firstVisibleItem,
                     int visibleItemCount,
                     int totalItemCount) {
    this.firstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
    Rect r = new Rect();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calculating the positon of the middle and then use `setSelection( int position )` to set the selection.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                 int firstVisibleItem,
                 int visibleItemCount,
                 int totalItemCount) {
  view.setSelection( visibleItemCount / 2 );
}
```